# menu.on('click', function() explanation

Tags: javascript

```
   (function() {

  var nav = $('nav'),
    menu = $('nav h1'),
    main = $('main'),
    open = true,
    hover = true;

  menu.on('click', function() {
        open != open ? false : true;
    nav.toggleClass('menu-active');
    main.toggleClass('menu-active');
    nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
    main.removeClass('menu-hover');

  });
  menu.hover( 
    function() {
      if (!open) {
        nav.addClass('menu-hover');
        main.addClass('menu-hover');
      }
    }, function() {
      nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
      main.removeClass('menu-hover');
    }
  );

})();
```

can some one explian me this js code to me?
esppeciay the menu.on('click', function() part.
and at the last there is () which is totally outofbounds exception for me i am new to js wanna know these stuffs for a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**

```
  menu.on('click', function());
```

'on' is a JQuery statement which listens to some event and executes a function when that event is satisfied.

In our case, it listens to the 'click' event on the 'menu' element. What it basically does is executes the function (callback function) whenever a user clicks on the menu element.

**Answer 2**

When a function is defined using the following syntax, it is called an Immediately-invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

```
  (function() {
    // Code goes here..    
  })();
```

We basically wrap the function in a set of parentheses, and immediately append another set of parentheses.

```
  (/* function */)();
```

This means the function will be immediately executed as soon as it is declared. These type of functions are usually used to not pollute the global namespace.

Additional links:

https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 0):

> In the snippet above there is an IIFE (immediately invoked function
>   expression)

to register a `click()` and `hover()` event on a menu which essentially is a navbar element.

This is a common behavior when you click on the menu it should expand/collapse that is what your `click()` function is doing.

When you click on the navbar,

- There is a flag `open` to maintain the navbar state (expanded|collapsed).
- Remove the classes set by hover event as currently the
  navbar is either opened or collapsed

In the `hover()` function,

If the menu is already opened then it will apply `.menu-hover` the class which should be giving some hover effects by making the background a bit darker or something.

I hope this pretty much answered your question.